# Evaluate Ember template programmatically

Tags: ember.js

I need to evaluate an Ember Template programmatically, so that I can generate the HTML that results by evaluating the Ember template within a supplied context.

I want to use this generated HTML to insert into a google maps InfoWindow (small modal that appears when you click on a marker.)

All of the variables will be unbound.

I have tried

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['templateName']( {context: 'suppliedHere})
```

but this expects a Ember.RenderBuffer to exist in the data.buffer object

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: have the same issue here. any suggestions?

Comment: I also have this issue, any ideas?

Comment: Hi @ianpetzer, I finally find solution here https://www.netguru.co/blog/rendering-templates-strings-emberjs. Hope this could help you and other people!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, inside your Ember view/component:

```
var viewClass = Ember.View.extend({ templateName: this.get('contentTemplate') });
var view = this.createChildView(viewClass);
var html = view.renderToBuffer().buffer;
```

Answer (score -2):

Ember uses [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for templating.

If you have the template as a string you can use Handlebars directly:

```
var template = 'Hi {{name}}';
var context = {name: 'John'};
Handlebars.compile(template)(context); //returns "Hi John"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer...I want to be able to use the template declared in a file, similarly to a partial. I also need to use Ember helpers such as {{#linkTo}}